# Rewind a database table in Oracle and return to the current state in real time

Tags: oracle, flashback

We are working on a new release of our product and we want to implement a feature where a user can view older data for a disease prediction made by the application. For example, the user would have an option to go back in time to see the predictions made one year ago. At the database level what needs to happen is to fetch archived data.The number of tables in the database is around 200 and out of them the tables that need to go back to an older state

```
I read about Flashbacks and although they seem to be used more for recovery, was curious to know if they can be used. 

1> Would it be possible to use Flashbacks? 
2> If yes, how would it affect performance?
3> If no what could be some other options?

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Flashback could be a way, but you need to use flashback data archive for the table you want. Using this technology, you can choose how much time you want to be able to store.  What i find interesting using flashback technology, is that you query the same table (with some aditional options), instead of the other option, of creating a history table.